# Google sign in does not work after publishing flutter web app

Tags: javascript, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-signin, flutter-web

I implemented google sign in on my flutter web app, it works fine in the debugging mode. I have to fix the web port with a command like flutter run -d chrome --web-port 5000 as I specified this port on the google credentials page

Below is my code for the login page

```
import 'package:car_of_your_dreams/Services/googleSignIn.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:car_of_your_dreams/Screens/Home_Screen.dart';


GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'profile',
    'email'
  ]
);

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State <LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();

}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  late String em;
  late String pa;
  GoogleSignInAccount ? currentUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount ? account) {
      setState(() {
        currentUser = account;
      });
    });
    _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: RawKeyboardListener(
        autofocus: true,
        focusNode: FocusNode(),
        onKey: (event) async {
          if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)) {
            print('enter key pressed');
            var dbCredentials = await MySQL().sendResponse(em, pa);

            if (dbCredentials == 'exists') {
              Provider.of < GoogleSignInAPI > (context, listen: false).nameOfCurrentUser = em;
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '1');
              print(dbCredentials);
            } else {
              Provider.of < CarsProvider > (context, listen: false).showToast();
              print(dbCredentials);
            }
          }
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          body: buildHomeScreen()
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  Widget buildHomeScreen() {
    if (currentUser != null) {
      Provider.of<GoogleSignInAPI>(context, listen: false).nameOfCurrentUser =
        currentUser?.displayName;
      print(Provider.of<GoogleSignInAPI>(context, listen: false).nameOfCurrentUser);
      Provider.of < GoogleSignInAPI > (context, listen: false).emailOfCurrentUser = currentUser?.email;
      MySQL().googleUp(currentUser?.displayName, currentUser?.email);
      return HomeScreen();
    } else return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amberAccent),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Sign in to continue', style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none))),
                  SizedBox(height: 12, ),
                  FractionallySizedBox(
                    widthFactor: 0.6,
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        Provider.of<CarsProvider>(context, listen: false).userEmail = value;
                        em = Provider.of<CarsProvider>(context, listen: false).userEmail!;

                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Email",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.amber, width: 2)
                        ),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5, ),
                  FractionallySizedBox(
                    widthFactor: 0.6,
                    child: TextField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        Provider.of<CarsProvider>(context, listen: false).userPassword = value;
                        pa = Provider.of<CarsProvider>(context, listen: false).userPassword!;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Password",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.amber, width: 2)),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key_outlined),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20), ))
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10, ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      TextButton(onPressed: () async {
                          var dbCredentials = await MySQL().sendResponse(em, pa);

                          if (dbCredentials == 'exists') {
                            Provider.of<GoogleSignInAPI>(context, listen: false).nameOfCurrentUser = em;
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '1');
                            print(dbCredentials);
                          } else {
                            Provider.of<CarsProvider>(context, listen: false).showToast();
                            print(dbCredentials);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Sign in', style: GoogleFonts.londrinaSolid(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.none))), ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10, ),
                      Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white, )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10, ),
                  SignInButton(Buttons.Google,
                    text: "Sign in with Google",
                    onPressed: _handleSignIn),
                  SizedBox(height: 7, ),
                  SignInButton(Buttons.Facebook,
                    text: "Sign in with Facebook",
                    onPressed: () {}),
                  SizedBox(height: 7, ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '-1');
                    },
                    child: Text('New user? Register..', style: GoogleFonts.londrinaSolid(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none))), ),
                  SizedBox(height: 50, ),

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> handleSignOut() async {
    await _googleSignIn.disconnect();

  }
}
```

When I published my web app on the web host, the google sign in button did not work. I get the message `NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'toString' on null`
The line in code of the main.dart.js javascript file that is supposedly producing this error is this:
`alv(a){if(typeof dartPrint=="function"){dartPrint(a) return}if(typeof console=="object"&&typeof console.log!="undefined"){console.log(a) return`

I checked everything in my code that could have a `toString` part, I found nothing related. I am not a javascript expert so I could not understand what is wrong with the javascript code generated by flutter. Any advice?
This is a snap shot from what I see in the browser console around the line that is supposedly generating the error: [image]

Comment: Have you completed the steps for Flutter Web? There's necessary meta tags and other settings that are mandatory to make it work: https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web

Comment: Yes all these steps are completed. As I mentioned, the google sign in works fine in the debugging mode. It is only the published version on the server that does not work.

Comment: is the release website full HTTPS SSL capable? Or HTTP?

Comment: It is HTTPS SSL capable. https://carkenz.com

Comment: Check out this post https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52338 may be this helpful

Comment: Thanks, this issues looks similar, looks like there is no straight-forward solution, I am going to try the code suggested in the last response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. I went back and checked the setup step by step, I found out that I put the meta tag `<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">`

in the `body` section of the index page where I should have put it in the `head` section of it.